# The Children in Rickchurian Mortydate Reference

Tags: rick-and-morty

I'm wondering what the hypnotized children in the fight between rick and the president are a reference to in season 3 episode 10.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Manchurian_Candidate

Comment: @Valorum I'm disappointed I was hoping that there was more to it.